# Is it possible to change the color of relationship lines in MySQL Workbench diagrams?

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench, database-diagrams

I have MySQL Workbench Community Edition 8.0.15 installed on my Mac OS 10.14.3. I'm currently working on making an ERD with Workbench's EER Diagram.

My problem is that whenever I export my diagram, the lines showing the relationships between tables are not visible because the background is white, and the lines are white.

[image]

It is visible on the editor because the background is black in workbench, but not when exported.

[image]

Is there any way to change the color of these lines? Or at least the background color of the diagram when it is exported so that the lines would at least be visible?

Comment: That's a known bug and an issue report has been created for it already.

Comment: @MikeLischke did you have the link of this issue?

Comment: @bchatard I think it's a bug in dark mode. The layout is fine if you change the appearance to light instead of using dark in system preferences > general.

Comment: @Rick yes in "light mode" everything is ok, but it's a poor workaround :(

Comment: I just updated MySQLWorkbench to version 8.0.22 on my Mac, and confirmed that this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to help. Close Workbench. Change the theme of your mac in clear mode. Restarts Workbench and saves again in pdf.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and get back to you on what happens. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! Finally, something that works